# Can't install pg gem

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, software-installation, ruby

I can't get the `pg gem` to install.  I have tried `--with-pg_config` and it didn't work.

> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header

If you haven't done it already, install and initialize [apt-file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt-file). This tool tells you what package contains a file with the given name.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Then run `apt-file search libpq-fe.h` to find out what package contains this file, and install the package in question. (It's [`libpq-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libpq-dev).)

You can also search for this file name in some package installation GUIs, or [online](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely due to missing postgresql development package. You can either install it manually or use the package manager from your distribution. Probably packages missing (install them with apt-get install):

1. libpq-dev
2. postgresql-server-dev-all

You can also try to install the ruby pg extension from your repository via `apt-get install libpgsql-ruby`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then

```
bundle gem install pg
```

then

```
bundle install
```

src:

http://wikimatze.de/installing-postgresql-gem-under-ubuntu-and-mac

Answer (score 0):

redfusion-team

First of all i want you to `apt-get installpostgresql`

then `apt-get install libpgsql-ruby`

then `apt-get install libpq-dev`

then do `apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all`

and finally `gem install pg -v 0.19.0`

IF you are trying to install metasploit then be sure to run this too after you have finishid the above

```
rvm use 2.3
bundle install
```

let us know if this worked for you ? We care abaut your problems, also if you ever need something else feel free to ask